# plotting xy, yz, zx planes

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a data list in the following form,

```
data = {x, y, z, f}
```

I would like to present three kinds of subdata set as a density (or contour) plot on the respective planes at once in one 3D graph.

1. `data1 = {x, y, f}`
2. `data2 = {y, z, f}`
3. `data3 = {x, z, f}`

How could I make an above kind of plot?

I really appreciate if anyone help me.

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y y + z z z
data = Flatten[Table[{{x, y, z}, f[x, y, z]}, {x, 0, 1, .1}, {y, 0, 1, .1}, {z, 0, 1, .1}], 2];
fi = Interpolation@data;
dpx = Rasterize@ DensityPlot[fi[0, y, z], {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Frame -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRangePadding -> 0];
dpy = Rasterize@ DensityPlot[fi[x, 0, z], {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Frame -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> "GreenPinkTones", PlotRangePadding -> 0];
dpz = Rasterize@ DensityPlot[fi[x, y, 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Frame -> False, 
    ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", PlotRangePadding -> 0];
Graphics3D[{
  {Texture@dpx, Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},
  {Texture@dpy, Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
  {Texture@dpz, 
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Many thanks. It helped.

Answer (score 2):

In versions 10.2+, you can use [SliceContourPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html) or [SliceDensityPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html) with `"BackPlanes"` as the second argument:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 - .5 y^2 - 2z^2

SliceContourPlot3D[f[x,y,z],"BackPlanes",{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},{z,-2,2}]
```

[image]

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[f[x,y,z],"BackPlanes",{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},{z,-2,2}]
```

[image]

```
data =Table[ f[x,y,z], {z, -2,2, 0.1}, {y,-2, 2, 0.1}, {x,-2, 2, 0.1}];
ListSliceContourPlot3D[data, "BackPlanes"]
```

[image]

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, "BackPlanes"]
```

[image]

The data can also be a list of `{x, y, z, f[z,y,z]}` 4-tuples. For

```
data0 = Flatten[Table[ {x,y,z,f[x,y,z]}, {z, -2,2, 0.1}, 
  {y,-2, 2, 0.1}, {x,-2, 2, 0.1}], 2];
```

`ListSliceContourPlot3D[data0, "BackPlanes"]` and `ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data0, "BackPlanes"]`give the same results as above.